# How to resend the last value of an observable every 1s

Tags: angular, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating an angular application using rxjs and firestore.

The function i'm working on need to update the percentage of a project.

Because it's resource intensive, i'm only updating the percentage of visible projects.

The percentage is calculated using the start date, the end date and the current date. So if we are halfway through the project, the percentage is going to indicate 50%.

Now i subscribe to the project, and use a formula to calculate the percentage and push it to the database. The thing is, i need to recalculate this percentage every 1s (or any number of time, i just need it to be accurate) so i can update the percentage accordingly.

This is what it look like:

```
var date_percentage = this.get("projects","uz9o3cGSHq7q1p7utujq").map(
      res=>{
        if (this.date_percentage_calculator(res.data().start_date,res.data().end_date) >= 100) return 100
        else if (this.date_percentage_calculator(res.data().start_date,res.data().end_date) <= 0) return 0
        else return this.date_percentage_calculator(res.data().start_date,res.data().end_date)
      }
    ).subscribe(calculated_percentage=>{

      this.update_proprety("projects","uz9o3cGSHq7q1p7utujq","percentage",calculated_percentage)

    })
```

Now the project might not be modified, and so the updater might only get called once.

How do i make the observable resend the latest value so it can update the percentage event if the observable didn't receive a value?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you have the number but you want to emit it every 1 second anyways, right?

```
this.get("projects","uz9o3cGSHq7q1p7utujq").map(res => {
  if (this.date_percentage_calculator(res.data().start_date,res.data().end_date) >= 100) 
    return 100
  else if (this.date_percentage_calculator(res.data().start_date,res.data().end_date) <= 0) 
    return 0
  else
    return this.date_percentage_calculator(res.data().start_date,res.data().end_date)
}).pipe(
  tap(percentage => doForEveryNewValue(percentage)),
  switchMap(percentage => timer(0, 1000).pipe(mapTo(percentage)))
)
```

This reemits the last result from the source observable every second.

RxViz: https://rxviz.com/v/j8Ang3ro

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this isn't quit what im looking for.
Let me put is this way: 
`
    var input = Observable.of(1,2,3);
    var do_somthing = input.subscribe(
      res=>{
        console.log(res)
      }
    ) 
`
now i need the do_somthing function to trigger for every new value or input AND to trigger every second with the latest value of input.

Comment: btw subscribe is something like the last step - you shouldn't do really much logic there.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you again for you answer, it's appreciated.

After playing with the answer and looking online i found a solution that do the job. I don't think its optimal, but it work for my needs.

Here is what it look like:

var temp = new BehaviorSubject(null);

```
var temp = new BehaviorSubject(null);

var temp2 = this.sub_to("projects", "uz9o3cGSHq7q1p7utujq").subscribe(
  res=>{
    temp.next({date1:res.payload.data()["start_date"],date2:res.payload.data()["end_date"]})
  }
)


temp.subscribe(
  res => {
    console.log(res)
    setTimeout(function(){ temp.next(temp.value) }, 30000);
    if (res){
      this.update_proprety("projects","uz9o3cGSHq7q1p7utujq","percentage",this.date_percentage_calculator(res.date1,res.date2))
    }

  }
)
```

temp2 is the project observable and when the projet is updated he change the value of temp2 who do the appropriate modifications.

now every 30 secconds temp2 change his value to his actual value, this way i can update the percentage event if the project is unchanged